# angularjs directive not called on load

Tags: angularjs, html

I have a angularjs directive and it's getting triggered on button click.But onload it's not getting triggered. Is there any way to execute the directive on page load from the controller ? 
Sorry for not sharing the code. Should I call $scope.$digest() ?? Or Shall I do a hidden button click to trigger the directive.

Raja K

Comment: Can't understand. Please add some code.

Comment: Please include the code for the custom directive.